# phpmyadmin failed to start due to Symfony/Polyfill errors

Tags: php, apache, symfony, phpmyadmin, polyfills

I opened PMA and I got this error:
**No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Cache/autoload.php on line 6**

I solved downgrading **php-symfony-polyfill-apcu** back to `1.6.0-2` (as I saw in another topic).
Although I got another error:

**Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Symfony/Polyfill/Mbstring/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/autoload.php on line 3**

I can't figure it out.
I'm on **ubuntu 18.04**, I use **apache** (running and working).
Hope somebody can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Please share more details - why did you start to fiddle around with the dependencies of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Ok I didn't modified anything in pma...
Someday I just opened and was crashed...maybe a system update could have broken it? I dunno...

Comment: Which details do you need? Apache log?

Comment: I got this too after upgrading, seems like there are broken dependencies in apt

Comment: I assumed it was such a thing...but I haven't figured out yet how to fix It...I'll continue to search and of I find something I'll keep you informed....meanwhile still hoping for somebody with a fresh solution :')